# How to deal with nil (while unwrapping an optional value) during visit to previous controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, crash, back, nsindexpath

In my controller 1, I have a table. Depending upon selection of the cell, an indexpath is segued to controller 2, which is also a table. With that segued indexpath, I have a CloudKit function that downloads the appropriate array from this indexpath, like so...

var newindex:IndexPath!

```
var restaurantArray: Array<CKRecord> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




func downloadRestaurants ()
{

    let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    var query:CKQuery

    switch newindex.row
    {
    case 0 :
        query = CKQuery(recordType: "american", predicate: predicate)
        self.typelabel.text = "American & European"
    case 1 :
        query = CKQuery(recordType: "asian", predicate: predicate)
        self.typelabel.text = "Asian, Oriental, Indian & Mediterranean"
    case 2 :
         query = CKQuery(recordType: "pubs", predicate: predicate)
        self.typelabel.text = "Burgers & Brew"

    default :
        query = CKQuery(recordType: "steakhouses", predicate: predicate)
        self.typelabel.text = "Steakhouses"
    }
  publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil)
    {
        (results, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
        else
        {
            for result in results!
            {
                self.restaurantArray.append(result)
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation( { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
downloadRestaurants()
}
```

However, when I selet one of these array instances, I am brought to one specific instance in controller 3. This is not the problem, but, when I go "Back" to select a different instance, my program crashes.  Which is understandable. Currently, my logic is set up to go from controller 1 to 2 to 3, but not from 3 to 2 based upon my indexpath/table function. Therefore, how would I be able to fix this small dilemma?

I'm on the fence how I would be able to alert controller 2 that (coming from table 3). I feel as though I could create another indexpath variable for controller 2 or I could create an in statement in controller 2, but I'm fuzzy on how I would go about that path. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In oder to inform class 2 from class 3 of anything you should use protocols / delegate methods. This can be done like this

```
 protocol MyClass3Delegate {
    func clicked()
}

class MyClass3: UIColletionViewCell  {
    var delegate : MyClass3Delegate?

   //call delegate?.clicked() when you dismiss the ViewController

 }
```

Then in prepareForSegue() you should call this

```
 if segue.identifier == "your identifier" {
     let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MyClass3
     destination.delegate = self
 }
```

and in your Class2 you should do this to extend the protocol:

```
 extension MyClass2: MyClass3 {
    func clicked() {
    //do your logic here
    }
 }
```